# Pass JSON String From ColdFusion To Javascript

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, lucee, coldfusion-2016

I am trying to pass a ColdFusion-generated JSON string as a parameter into a Javascript function.  I'm getting an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" error I think because of some combination of single and double quotes that just aren't organized right.

Here is some sample code:

```
<script>
    function myJSFunction(z) {
        console.log(z);
    }
</script>

<cfset x = {"firstName"="Bob", "lastName"="Smith"} />
<cfdump var="#x#" />
<cfset y = serializeJSON(x) />
<cfdump var="#y#" />

<cfoutput>
<a href="javascript:myJSFunction('#y#');">Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token</a><br/>
</cfoutput>
```

I've tried experimenting with JSStringFormat, but that didn't seem to help.  Any thoughts or suggestions on how to pass the JSON string would be helpful.  Thx!

(I'm running on Lucee 5.2.6.60.)

Answer (score 4):

Couple things.

In order to output JSON data or any object in the console, you have to stringify that bad boy. This can be done in JQuery with `Stringify`.

Also, it took several rounds of testing and tweaking in order to output the HTML correctly - on Chrome at least. The hyperlink seriously did not like all the double quotes and nothing I tried would escape them. I swapped it out with a button and used onClick instead. I got the following code to work.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>


<script>
    function myJSFunction(z) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(z));
    }
</script>

<cfset x = {"firstName"="Bob", "lastName"="Smith"} />
<cfdump var="#x#" />
<cfset y = serializeJSON(x) />
<cfdump var="#y#" />

<cfoutput>
<button onclick='myJSFunction(#y#);'>test</button><br/>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: I couldn't get it to work at first either. Seemed to at first, but adding a value with a single quote broke it again.  [EncodeForJavaScript](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/encodeforjavascript.html) seemed to do the trick `<a href='javascript:myJSFunction("#encodeForJavaScript(serializeJSON(x))#");'>Test</a>`

Comment: That's a good thought, but like most of my tests, single quotes break it, `x = {"firstName"="Bob", "lastName"="Smith", "Nick"="O'Reilly"}`. It needs to be wrapped in something like encodeForJavaScript